# Running OSX as a syslog server

Tags: macos, router, logging, syslog, asl

I want to receive the logs from my router (an ASUS RT68U) on my laptop (OSX 10.9). It supports syslog and OSX has [ASL](http://real-world-systems.com/docs/syslogd.a.html) (a superset of syslog, apparently). I've followed the instructions in [OS X Lion as a syslog server](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/OS_X_Lion_as_a_syslog_server) but the Console shows nothing under /var/log/network (though the directory does show).

The steps I've taken:

- Set the IP of my laptop in the router's admin page for syslogging.
- Updated the syslog plist to listen on the network.
- Created the directory (/var/log/network) to log into.

This is where I diverge slightly from the instructions as with many things in /etc on OSX, if it also has a sub folder structure you're better off adding your conf in there and leaving the main one alone. So,

- Added an ASL conf. **This is where I think the problem lies.**

#### /etc/asl/asus-router

```
# Asus router logs
? [A= Host router.asus.com] store_directory /var/log/network uid=0 gid=20 mode=0644 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
# I've also tried:
#? [= Host 192.168.1.1] …
#? [A= Host 192.168.1.1] …
#? [= Host router.asus.com] …
#? [= Sender router.asus.com] …
#? [A= Sender router.asus.com] …
#? [= IP router.asus.com] …
#? [A= IP router.asus.com] …
```

- Unloaded and loaded the syslog plist to pick up the new conf.
- Logged in to the router via SSH. This helpfully adds a log entry and I got the following info:

#### ssh'd into the router

```
nvram show | grep log_level
size: 50509 bytes (15027 left)
log_level=6

ps | grep syslog
 9358 iain  1488 S    /sbin/syslogd -m 0 -S -O /tmp/syslog.log -s 256 -l 6 -R 192.168.1.140:514 -L
```

Finally, I turned off the firewall and ran `sudo tcpdump udp port 514`. I can see logs coming in but nothing shows up in the Console even if I reload the plist.

```
06:21:38.983497 IP router.asus.com.40420 > iains-air.syslog: SYSLOG authpriv.info, length: 86
```

I've even taken a look at [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) to see if I could glean how I might match on the hostname, but as ever with RFC's, they're pretty abstract. The only thing I can think to do is edit /etc/syslog.conf, but I wouldn't know with what.

Any suggestions or insights would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: The router configuration is [described here](https://fatmin.com/2015/01/04/configure-syslog-logging-levels-on-the-asus-rt-ac66u-router/) and that of OSX [is here](http://meinit.nl/enable-an-apple-mac-os-x-machine-as-a-syslog-server). Add info to the post if this does not work.

Comment: @harrymc There's nothing to add because the only thing from those I haven't done is to add the line to /etc/syslog.conf, which I did and nothing happened, but the conf has "# Note that flat file logs are now configured in /etc/asl.conf" so it seems that line is unnecessary anyway. I think the problem lies in the asl conf but finding good examples for it is hard.

Comment: @harrymc That's the one I linked at the top of my question ;-)

Comment: Oups. Have you traced to see where is the problem? The choice is between the router not sending or OSX ignoring (or both). I would also search for all files with `asl` in their name.

Comment: On the Mac, run `sudo lsof -nPi 4 | grep :514` to see if anything's actually listening on the syslog port (514/UDP). If not, you might not have successfully edited your syslogd launchctl plist, or you didn't unload and reload it.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks. That command shows both launchd and syslogd are listening. I guess that's how it should look as launchd probably sets up and hands off to syslog but maybe launchd should stop being a listener? I checked the plist is valid and unloaded then loaded using launchctl too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, needed a syslog server running on my OSX platform to capture syslog events from my network devices. I solved this issue by downloading and installing the following application "Lan-Secure Mac Syslog Server" that can be found on the following link: http://www.lan-secure.com/SyslogServerMac.htm

Once I installed the software that was very simple as just running the installer, my OSX platform starts collecting syslog events and display them on the software console. I also enabled the email notifications feature so I'll be able to be informed immediately about critical events.